# How to remove duplicate pages from search engine

Tags: google-search-console

I have duplicate content from my home page.

In Google Webmasters they tell me that I have a problem with duplicate content:

[image: Duplicates]

For example:

```
www.example.com/page1/   www.example.com/page2/    www.example.com/page2/
```

How can I remove it?

Comment: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask; 2. your screenshot is not viewable on SO, people have to go to another page to view it; 3. Tell us what you've tried first.

Answer (score 0):

What that page says is not that you have duplicate *pages* but that you have several pages with the same [meta description](https://moz.com/learn/seo/meta-description):

> Meta descriptions are HTML attributes that provide concise summaries of webpages. They commonly appear underneath the blue clickable links in a search engine results page.

Usually each page should have their own meta description that describes its content (that is the reason why Google warns you about duplicates), but sometimes it's OK that several pages share the same description.

For example, based in your screen shot your site appears to be about mobile phones, let's say that the duplicates with 2 pages are one for the summary of the phone and the other for the technical specifications (I'm supposing as I don't understand Arabic), the meta description of both pages could be similar but not exact because it should reflect that they cover different aspects of the phone (summary vs technical spec).

On the other hand the duplicate with 14 pages appears to be several pages from a product list, maybe phones with same tag, if this is correct then it's OK that all those pages have the same meta description, as they are just parts of the same topic split into several pages.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in the subject
But there are some ways you can solve the problem
Several months ago I read an article about this problem
The solution is a code that tells Google to index this page and does not index the subpages
But in fact I tried a lot to get to this article and I could not reach it again
But there are some solutions to this problem